# JsTree - Show quantity on each node

Tags: javascript, jstree

I am using jstree to visualize products in a tree.
Now I want to show quantity of the products.
I can easily do that by adding a number in the text, but if I do the user can change quantity when renaming node. I don't want the user to change quantity that way (they do it on a separate product page).

How can I show quantity in jstree but not putting the quantity in the text (so the user not can rename it)?
I am using customized icons for differen product types so I can not use the icon to show quantity on each node.

Example:
I would like to visulation each node like below:

*[icon] [quantity] [text/title]*

And when renamning I only want to rename the text/title (not the quantity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could play with pseudo elements and generated content. For example you could pass data-attribute to node link by specifying `a_attr`.

```js
 $('#container').jstree({
    'core' : {
      'data' : [
        {
          "text" : "Root node",
          "a_attr": {
            "data-quantity": 120
          },
          "children" : [
            { 
              "text" : "Child node 1",
              "a_attr": {
                 "data-quantity": 100
              }
            },
            { 
              "text" : "Child node 2",
              "a_attr": {
                 "data-quantity": 20
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  });
```

```css
.jstree-anchor {
  position: relative;
}

.jstree-anchor::before {
  content: attr(data-quantity);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 24px;
}

a[data-quantity] > .jstree-icon {
  margin-right: 28px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.3/themes/default/style.min.css" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.3/jstree.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you works great for me! Just som graphic modification to match my design.

Comment: Excellent answer! I switched to a badge _after_ the node name using `position: relative;` and some coloring and sizing. Thanks so much!